# Using or The use?

Tags: sentence-structure

Which one of "using" or "the use" is correct in this sentence:

> This line of code was commented after contacting the support team of "X Comapny". Several points should be noted about working in network mode. There is no need to use "MethodX" Function in this case. Only **using** "UserPassWord" Property is required.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are okay, though I would actually go with **the use of**. For example:

**You do not need to use X. The use of Y is sufficient.**

or

**You do not need to use X. Using Y is sufficient.**

Answer (score 0):

The infinitive "to use" and the gerund "using" are grammatical and idiomatic locutions in this paragraph. What is not idiomatic is the absence of the definite article preceding their complements.

As a matter of style, the paragraph is somewhat ambiguous. It may mean

**In this case, either the X or the Y can be used** or **In this case, the  Y must be used rather than the X.**

The ambiguity does not arise due to errors in grammar; it arises from poor choice of words and verbosity. "Not required" does not mean "not sufficient. "Only Y" in this context may mean "no more than Y" rather than "Nothing but Y."